# Crystal Report to BI conversion - Query Expression

Tags: crystal-reports-8.5, peoplesoft-query

We are currently in the process of upgrade to PeopleTools 8.56 and eventually to 8.59 and as such, we have to convert the Crystal Reports to BI publisher.

In one of the Crystal reports, They have an expression as below and named it @Worked

Worked is an expression

if {AG_OTIME_LV_PAID.EXP10_8} = 'BOOKED' then

{AG_OTIME_LV_PAID.TIME_QUANTITY}

else

0;

Paid is also an expression named @Paid

if {AG_OTIME_LV_PAID.EXP10_8} = 'PAID' then

{AG_OTIME_LV_PAID.TIME_QUANTITY}

else

0

How do I implement this calculation in PeopleSoft Query manager?

Sum ({@Worked}, {AG_OTIME_LV_PAID.EMPLID}) - (Sum ({@paid}, {AG_OTIME_LV_PAID.EMPLID}));

Report name - AGOTPDBL in PeopleSoft Financials/SCM 9.2[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnyMQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h6B8.png)

I tried to have an expression